# What's wrong with my sed command (BSD sed) regexp substitution

Tags: macos, sed

I have a file called `samconfig.toml`

```
version = 0.1
~~~
parameter_overrides = "CognitoUserPoolName=\"aaa\" ApiAllowOrigin=\"'https://dev.xxxxxxxxx.amplifyapp.com'\" etc..
~~~
```

My sed command

```
sed -i '' -e "s#ApiAllowOrigin=\\\"'https.*com'\\\"#ApiAllowOrigin=\\\"'https://dev.yyyyyyyy.amplify.com'\\\"#g" ./samconfig.toml
```

It doesn't substitute the url. What's confusing about this, is that it contains all those single quotes, double quotes, back slashes..

I even checked with visualized regexp checker

[image]

Comment: Enclosing sed commands within double quotes may have side effects it is safer to enclose those commands with single quotes. Single quotes can be represented by `\'` within a shell e.g. `sed 'blah'\''blah'\''blah' file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed` on macos:

```bash
sed -i.bak -E "s~(ApiAllowOrigin=\\\\\"'https://).*(\.com'\\\\\")~\1dev.yyyyyyyy.amplify\2~" file

cat file

version = 0.1
~~~
parameter_overrides = "CognitoUserPoolName=\"aaa\" ApiAllowOrigin=\"'https://dev.yyyyyyyy.amplify.com'\" etc..
~~~
```

Here:

- When inside the double quotes you will need to use `\\\\` to match a single `\`.
- Note use or `-E` for extended regular expressions
- We are using 2 capture groups to avoid repeating same pattern in match and substitution

Comment: Sorry I'll try this later, thank you so much you've saved me